# concatenate multiple InputStreams and ensure newline

Tags: java, newline, inputstream

I would like to read multiple files from an SFTP directory and concatenate it into one resultfile.
So the SFTP API returns InputStreams and I used a SequenceInputStream to concatenate them.
As long as all csv files end with an empty line, this is working fine but if they don't, the last line of one file and the first line of another file get appended without newline.

I'm trying to find an elegant way to solve this but am unable to find one.
So what I would like to do is be able to look at the last line of an InputStream and ensure it is a newline. If not, append it.
Or if you have a better solution, please let me know.
I would like to not go through the whole files and check their content at this time.

Comment: It would help if you would show some code as to what you currently have (so it's more of a "insert this there" or a "this is what you did wrong" rather than a "here's how you do it").

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap a custom FilterInputStream around the InputStream returned from the sftp api and when you read the last byte of the file, verify that it is a newline.  if not, add another byte before returning to the data to the caller.